# HTML5 version of Angry Birds not rendering properly in any browser

Tags: firefox, games, chromium, xubuntu, html5

See the attached screenshot. When I run Angry Birds in any of my browsers, pieces of the game are missing.  This desktop is 32bit Xubuntu with the PAE kernel, if that affects anything.  I've tried with Chromium, Chrome, and Firefox to no avail.

I have the 64bit version of Xubuntu on my laptop and the game appears to work just fine.

[image: angry birds]

Comment: Also doesn't render properly on Kubuntu 11.04 32bit Firefox 4.0.1.

Comment: What graphics card and drivers are you using?

Comment: It's an Nvidia GeForce 6200 (256MB), I believe.  I've got Nvidia's restricted drivers installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to "NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 173)" from the "version current" in the Additional Drivers dialog resolved the issue.

Comment: This is true, but on my Geforce Go 7400 the performance is so bad it is unplayable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have flash installed? I saw on twitter the other day that flash is used for some parts of the game though the tweet was in relation to ie9 it may be true for other browsers as well.

Comment: Think that was only for the sound.

Comment: I believe flash is only used for sound.  It's definitely installed.  The odd thing is the near identical setup (as far as Xubuntu is concerned) between the two machines.  I think I may try running dpkg --get-selections and compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

There is an SD and an HD version.  By default the high-def version was selected.  Pick the SD version and it should Just Work.

Ironically, it is MUCH faster in Firefox 6 than in the Chrome browser.